# Why am I not able to install flutter on my 32 bit windows 10 machine?

Tags: flutter, dart

i can't finish installation of flutter

i m running windows 10 32bit but dart cant install for using flutter

C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe not compatible with Windows version installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flutter is not supported for 32 bit machines. You need a 64 bit.

> **To install and run Flutter, your development environment must meet these minimum requirements:**
>   Operating Systems: Windows 7 SP1 or later (64-bit)
>   Disk Space: 400 MB (does not include disk space for IDE/tools).

[Reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Answer (score 3):

I am extremely sorry, nobody can help you for now.

> Support for 32-bit Windows isn't currently planned. If our assumptions
>   are incorrect and there's a very significant demand, we might
>   re-evaluate that decision.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14925

All you can do for now draft an petition and share it with all your 32 bit software developer friends and ask them to support it. If your able to gather enough support, the Flutter Dev team will help you for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Now we can install Flutter on Windows 32 Bit. But, You can install it manually via git. If you need Dart for windows 32 Bit is here https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/release/2.14.0-336.0.dev/sdk/dartsdk-windows-ia32-release.zip.
Finally Flutter run like this pic:
[Flutter on Windows 32 Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu4qo.jpg)